# Unable to ssh on Google cloud instance

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I was sshed to my gcloud instance. I was suddenly logged out with following error:

```
Timeout, server 104.198.148.233 not responding.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors for troubleshooting hints.
```

On trying again I am getting following:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/aapa/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 104.198.148.233 [104.198.148.233] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/aapa/.ssh/google_compute_engine type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/aapa/.ssh/google_compute_engine-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2
```

How to can I find the issue? What steps should I take.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Compute Engine: How to snapshot a VM's disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27345534/google-compute-engine-how-to-snapshot-a-vms-disk)

Answer (score 1):

The error is "key_load_public: No such file or directory". The timeout error suggests reading the troubleshooting guide: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors.

The guide says possible cause for the error can be a full disk or networking problems. Is your disk full ?. You can check by accessing your instance from the SSH console.

Comment: Was unable to ssh from console. But trying taking snapshot of the disk. According to the snapshot the disk is 70% free. And regarding networking, I was able to ping the server.

Comment: You should be able to ssh from console. What error do you get?. Maybe a firewall on your end is blocking outgoing ssh connections.

The error line: "debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory" suggests that the public key cannot be found on the server, so your private key cannot be verified.